# Deserialization problem while loading objects

Tags: c#, deserialization

My aim is to set the bool values where they left of by reading from txt.

Here is my problem, simply, and step by step;

1. I set the values to "true" by clicking the set button
2. In txt file, JSON objects are set to true successfully
3. I **closed and re-run** the program
4. I expect the current bool flags to be "true" from previous run

**However they are still false**, I there is a problem with "**deserialize**"
Button2_Click_1 is just showing me the current values of the flags.
Another point is that in the txt file flags are still true which seems okay.

I changed the order of deserialize and serialize yet nothing changed.

```
   [Serializable]
    class Class1
    {
        public bool flag { get; set; }
        public bool flag2 { get; set; }
        public Class1()
        {
            flag = false;
            flag2 = false;
        }
    }

[Serializable]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();


        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c1.flag = true;
            c1.flag2 = true;

            //deserialize
            string json2 = File.ReadAllText("path.txt");
            Class1 f2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(json2);

            //serialize
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c1);
            File.WriteAllText("path.txt", json);


            Console.WriteLine(json);


        }

        private void Button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current Status of Flag1: "+c1.flag);
            Console.WriteLine("Current Status of Flag2: " + c1.flag2);
        }
```

Comment: In your constructor of `Class1` you're always setting those values to `false`, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Why do you expect previous runs of the program will contain the same variable values of a new instantiation of the program when you always set them as `false` to start?  You don't appear to save those values, or load them upon instantiation either.

Comment: You're missing a key idea behind serialization of state. You serialize state to save it to disk or some other non-volatile medium. You deserialize it to read it from that medium and populate your application with that saved state. In your code, you're not doing anything with your deserialized state. `f2` is not used anywhere.

Comment: Your variable "Class1 f2" is only local to the click routine and will not be recognized by the rest of your code.  You have to define the f2 as a global variable for the rest of the application to see the data you read from the file

Comment: @dcg although I remove the false initialization in constructor, it still gives me false

Comment: @jdweng I can not make it public it gives an error

Comment: Move the definition outside of the click method.

Comment: You expect `c1.flag1` and `c1.flag2` to be true after you close and re-open the application? But, you're never deserializing the contents of `"path.txt"` to `c1`. Your step-by-step process seems to be missing the actual deserialization step. Try checking to see if `"path.txt"` exists, then doing `c1 = JsonConvert.DeserialieObject<Class1>(File.ReadAllText("path.txt"))` in the constructor of `Form1`.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson Thank you it worked when I apply your advice :) !

Answer (score 3):

If you are clicking Button2 without first clicking Button1 when the application starts up, c1 will be false by default since the default value of a boolean is false. if you wish to load the json when you click Button2 please add the following code above Console.WriteLine:

```
c1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(File.ReadAllText("path.txt"));
```

so that it becomes

```
    private void Button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(File.ReadAllText("path.txt"));
        Console.WriteLine("Current Status of Flag1: "+c1.flag);
        Console.WriteLine("Current Status of Flag2: " + c1.flag2);
    }
```

and this should fix your issue

Comment: In my main program (4K lines of code) there is no such button, I have removed the false initialization in constructor, I replace your "Deserialize" with mine in Button1_Click method. It didn't work. Still gives false.

Comment: @Selen even if you dont initialize to false. All bool values are by default false.

Comment: in your button2_click method. Dont use c1 object. Try creating a local variable and read the content of the file. Then read it and print it. I am suggesting a local variable because, you are misusing the class level variable c1.

Comment: @Carbine I created a new object c2 in local, I used it instead of  f2, it says it is unused

Comment: f2 is unused from the above code, rightly so. What are you doing with f2? Why do you need it?

Comment: @Carbine I just want to perform deserialization,  I am not sure with f2 too.